# Windows 95 VM not booting on VMware

Tags: vmware, windows-95

So I finish the first reboot when I try to install windows 95 and when I boot. All I get is this "While initializing device IOS: Windows protection error. You need to restart your computer." I don't know why this is happening? Btw I'm using VMware Workstation Pro. I tried to change the RAM, but it still didn't work. I tried to turn stuff off it had no difference.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What VMware product are you using? Player, Workstation, vSphere, …? How is it set up? Did you select Windows 95 as the guest OS? Did you assign more than 512 MiB RAM? Did you add any (historically) exotic virtual hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Windows 95 running on VMware Workstation Pro V16.2.3 and it works fine.

Make sure you do not try to overpower the Windows 95 Guest.

Memory: 256 MB. More not really needed.  512 MB will likely work.

Disk:  2 GB.  No need to assign scads of disk and native Windows 95 has limits.

CPU:  1 CPU, 1 Core.  Definitely do not assign multiple CPUs.

Graphics Acceleration:  Disabled.

Check all your settings.

With respect to Windows 95, there were a number of patches and you need most of them.  You will need to search the Internet for stuff that old.

VMware should have installed VMware Tools.

Try different hardware versions (Vmware, VM tab, change hardware compatibility. Try older hardware.

Look through and check all I mentioned. As noted, my Windows 95 machine runs.

Comment: Is there any chance you could share a VM that has Win95 running? I've been struggling with the CPU issue for a few days now, and can't get the patches right. Would be a huge help if you could share a working VM. Thanks

Comment: I made the VM a long time ago and machines are large and cannot be shared here.

Comment: Also make sure your host machine is slower than 2 GHz.  I can run Windows 95 on an older computer but not on this newer and faster computer.  That just means that Windows 95 will not longer run inside a VM because the Host Hardware is too fast. On the faster machine I can still start it in Safe Mode.

Comment: I have Windows 95 running in VMware Workstation Pro V16 set up as I said in my answer. It is running on an X1 Carbon 4th generation machine. I put the very same Windows 95 machine on my X1 Carbon 9th generation machine and it is not start in normal mode (protection error) .  Nothing to be done (in my research so far) except use a slower host machine.